# Use maven exec plugin with hyphen in arguments

Tags: maven, npm, command-line-arguments, maven-plugin

I am trying to perform a npm build from maven, but I am having a problem getting the commandline arguments right.

I am using the following snippet

```
<execution>
    <id>npm run build (compile)</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <configuration>
        <executable>npm</executable>
        <workingDirectory>${my.source.directory}</workingDirectory>  
        <arguments>
            <argument>run</argument>
            <argument>build</argument>
            <argument>--base-href</argument>
            <argument>/my-base-href/</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

I have tried several variations of the `<argument>`'s, but none of them work.

```
<argument>--base-href</argument>
<argument>/my-base-href/</argument>
or
<argument>-base-href</argument>
<argument>/my-base-href/</argument>
or
<argument>"--base-href"</argument>
<argument>/my-base-href/</argument>
or
<argument><![CDATA[--base-href]]></argument>
<argument>/my-base-href/</argument>
or
<commandlineArgs>run build --base-href /my-base-href/</commandlineArgs> (instead of <arguments>)

leads to
$ npm build "/my-base-href/"
problem: missing '--base-href'
```

```
<argument>"--base-href /my-base-href/"</argument>

leads to
$ npm build
problem: missing '--base-href "/my-base-href/"'
```

```
<argument>&hyphen;&hyphen;base-href</argument>
<argument>/my-base-href/</argument>

leads to
problem: pom error, could not resolve entity named 'hyphen' (same with &dash;)
```

```
<argument>\-\-base-href</argument>
<argument>/my-base-href/</argument>
leads to
$ ng build "\-\-base-href" "/my-base-href/"
problem: escape chars ending up in command
```

What is happening here? Why does maven eat the argument starting with `--` and how can I make it less tasty?

(Tried with windows 8.1, maven 3.3.9 and 3.5.4, exec plugin 1.3.9 and 1.6.0)

Comment: What is the error message, if you do <argument>--base-href /my-base-href</argument>? Based on the documentation, this should work (https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html).

Comment: Yeah, tried that but did forgot to re-create when posting this question. It then runs `npm build`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if if exactly the same, but I needed to pass in the --coverage flag to a test run. To get this I ended up needing to give `--` first: `npm run test -- --coverage`

```
        <argument>run</argument>
        <argument>test</argument>
        <argument>--</argument>
        <argument>--coverage</argument>
```